# pgrouting: function driving_distance does not exist

Tags: qgis, postgresql, pgrouting

I tried to run driving distance function but got error.

```
   function driving_distance(unknown, integer, integer, boolean, boolean) does not exist
    LINE 1: SELECT * FROM driving_distance('
                          ^
    HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.




SELECT * FROM driving_distance('
          SELECT gid AS id,
              start_id::int4 AS source,
              end_id::int4 AS target,
              shape_leng::float8 AS cost
          FROM roads',
          15137,
          100000,
          false,
          false)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use pgr_drivingdistance, as per [the documentation](http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.0/en/src/driving_distance/doc/dd_driving_distance.html#pgr-driving-distance).

To check what pgRouting functions are available (ie. to see if they installed correctly, you can run this query in the database with PGRouting installed:

```
SELECT  p.proname
FROM    pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
JOIN    pg_catalog.pg_proc p
ON      p.pronamespace = n.oid
WHERE   n.nspname = 'public'

and p.proname LIKE 'pgr%'

order by p.proname
```

The **pg_catalog** schema is the standard PostgreSQL meta data and core schema. You will find pre-defined global postgres functions in here as well as useful meta data about your database that is very specific to postgres. This is the schema used by postgres to manage things internally. A lot of this information overlaps with information found in the information_schema, but for data present in the information_schema, the information_schema is much easier to query and requires fewer or no joins to arrive at basic information.  as per http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/20-The-Anatomy-of-PostgreSQL-Part-2-Database-Objects.html

Comment: Thank you!. Can I ask what pg_catalog is?

Comment: @daydayup updated my answer