# pgrouting functions does not exist but I installed it

Tags: pgrouting

I have a Debian 11 server running with PostgreSQL 13 and PostGIS. I invoked `apt` to install pgrouting like the following snippet

```bash
$ # search the package on apt?
$ sudo apt update
$ apt-cache search pgrouting
postgresql-13-pgrouting - Routing functionality support for PostgreSQL/PostGIS
postgresql-13-pgrouting-doc - Routing functionality support for PostgreSQL/PostGIS (Documentation)
postgresql-13-pgrouting-scripts - Routing functionality support for PostgreSQL/PostGIS - SQL scripts

$ sudo apt install postgres-13-pgrouting
```

I went to my `psql` console as usual

```
$ psql db
db=> select version()
PostgreSQL 13.7 (Debian 13.7-0+deb11u1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

db=> create extension postgis;
db=> create extension pgrouting;
```

checking my version

```sql
gridnetwork=> select postgis_version(); select pgr_version();

postgis_version
---------------------------------------
3.1 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1
(1 row)
pgr_version
-------------
3.1.3
(1 row)
```

however I tried any of the `pgr` functions, they don't exist! For instance,

```sql
db=> select pgr_createtopology()

ERROR:  function pgr_createtopology() does not exist
LINE 1: select pgr_createtopology();
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I also tried with sample data, fill in the function's parameters, and still it won't invoke. I did `select pgr_version()` and it returns that I have 3.1.3 installed

I checked this [thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155146/pgrouting-function-driving-distance-does-not-exist)  and it returns that I have the functions listed. Postgis can connect to QGIS

Why can't I invoke any of the `pgrouting` functions?

Answer (score 1):

I reinstalled the pgrouting with apt

```
$ sudo apt remove postgresql-13-pgrouting
```

then build again from source, instead of version 3.3.3, I used 3.3.1

```
$ wget -O pgrouting-3.3.1.tar.gz https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/releases/download/v3.3.1/pgrouting-3.3.1.tar.gz
```

follow the instruction from the official site [how to install pgrouting](https://docs.pgrouting.org/3.1/en/pgRouting-installation.html) and just built the pgrouting.

somehow everything works now, topology is created.

```
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake  ..
$ make
$ sudo make install
```